# Hide if get_the_category() returns no results

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm listing related pages based on category. This is what I'm using to list all related categories. What I'm trying to do is hide the entire block if it doesn't return any categories. I'm not sure how to do that with the foreach.

```
<h3>Related Category</h3>
<ul>
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $catCS) { 
    if($catCS->parent == 4){ ?> 
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(46); ?><?php echo $catCS->slug; ?>"><?php echo $catCS->cat_name; ?></a></li>  
<?php }
    } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check for the length of the objects it is returning. Process it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you know, but WordPress have a command to get parent categories `get_category_parents`, so if you use that you could use it like this:

```
<?php
$result = get_category_parents($cat, true, '</li><li>');
$result = substr($result, 0, -4);
if(!is_wp_error($result))
{
?>
    <h3>Related Category</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $result; ?>
    </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

NOTE: `substr` is a small hack to remove the last empty `<li>` opening due to how I am using `</li><li>` as a separator.

---

This is untested, but you could filter the current array into a resulting array and test if that is empty or not.

```
<?php
# save the result
$categories = array();
# fill $categories if any match
foreach ((get_the_category()) as $cat)
{
    if($cat->parent == 4)
    {
        $categories[] = $cat;
    }
}

# print nothing if $categories is empty
if (!empty($categories))
{
?>
<h3>Related Category</h3>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($categories as $catCS)
{
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(46); ?><?php echo $catCS->slug; ?>"><?php echo $catCS->cat_name; ?></a></li>  
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

There might be a better way but this should work.

Comment: @user1272433 see the first example its a lot cleaner.